# How to get window handle by PID in autohotkey?

Tags: autohotkey

I want to get window handle by PID in autohotkey, because title of the window is always changing. If anyone wonder, I want to get handle of last.fm main window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [WinGet](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/WinGet.htm) command with the Cmd paramter as `ID`.

> Cmd is the operation to perform, which if blank defaults to ID.
> ID: Retrieves the unique ID number of a window. Also known as the window handle (HWND).

[WinTitle](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/misc/WinTitle.htm) can be a PID.

```
WinGet, UniqueID, ID, ahk_pid %VarContainingPID%
```

Another option is [WinExist()](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/WinExist.htm)

```
UniqueID := WinExist("ahk_pid" . VarContainingPID)
```

Answer (score 8):

To get the first window Class/ID of a PID you can do the following:

```
Process, Exist, "notepad.exe"
NewPID = %ErrorLevel%  ; Save the value immediately since ErrorLevel is often changed.
if NewPID
{ ; process exists!
    WinGetClass, ClassID, ahk_pid %NewPID%   ; ClassID will be read here for the process
    WinGetTitle, Title, ahk_pid %NewPID% ; Title will contain the processe's first window's title
    IfWinExist ahk_class %ClassID% ; this will find the first window by the ClassID
    {
        WinGet, WinID, ID ; this will get the ID of the window into WinID variable
        WinActivate ; this will bring this window to front (not necessary for example)  
        ListVars ; this will display your variables
        Pause
    }
    IfWinExist %Title% ; this will find the first window with the window title
    {
        WinGet, WinID, ID
        WinActivate ; this will bring this window to front (not necessary for example)  
        ListVars
        Pause
    }
}
```

there are other methods to convert the PID other than IfWinExist I'm sure, and it is possible to have more than one process with same class ID.  :)
Additionally you can use

Comment: I haven't closely studied the question/answer in particular, but are you sure @Suitup s answer is incorrect? It has been accepted as correct by OP.

Comment: It answers the  opposite of the question.  Thus - it is wrong

Comment: A process can have as many as [10,000 windows](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20070718-00/?p=25963). Use `ID` and `IDLast` in _winget_ with your `ahk_PID`. If the result is the same, there is only one hwnd.

Answer (score 1):

As a reusable function:

```
getHwndForPid(pid) {
    pidStr := "ahk_pid " . pid
    WinGet, hWnd, ID, %pidStr%
    return hWnd
}
```